# AD&D 1e Cleric / Thief Weapons (by the book)

Tags: adnd-1e, cleric, thief, multi-classing

Talking to my DM for a new campaign last night about playing a Cleric / Thief, he's suggested that Cleric Thieves shouldn't be allowed to use edged weapons.

BtB is there anything that contradicts this?

His view is based on the fact that the PHB specifically states that Cleric / "Fighter-type" multi-classes can use edged weapons but says nothing about other Cleric multi-classes, therefore he says by exclusion (that is as nothing is stated) they can't.

My view would be if you say that a thief can only use weapons available to both thieves and clerics you're limiting it to a club which seems improbable that that was intended...

Views? Ideally with citations from the PHB / DMG?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 33 of the PHB states

> Cleric combinations (with fighter types) may use edged
>   weapons.

But later on it states

> Cleric/Magic-user: This combination
>   gives the character a great variety
>   and selection of spells, as well as
>   the use of armor and more weapons. Hit
>   points are somewhat better than those
>   of the magic-user class alone.
>   Half-elves may be cleric/magic-users.

If the Cleric/Magic-user can use the non blunt weapons of a magic user then it follows that that the 1/2 Orc Cleric/Thief can use the Thief weapon list as well.

Coupled with the note for half orcs on page 16

> When playing a multi-classed
>   character, the half-orc must abide by
>   the restrictions of the least
>   favorable class with regard only to
>   armor.

You have a good case for your interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Found it:

It's in the race section on half orcs (the only race who can play Cleric Thieves).

In the case of Half-Orcs "When playing multi-class characters, the half-orc must abide by the restrictions of the least favourable class with regard to armour only."  (PHB p.16)

So you can't wear chainmail but can carry a sword.